# How can Multi-image TIFF files be split with PHP?

Tags: php, image-manipulation, tiff

I've got a client who needs me to use PHP to split a [TIFF](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tagged_Image_File_Format) image (which contains 2 or 3 images, sort of like an animated GIF) into its component images.

Can ImageMagick or one of the other graphic libraries do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From a quick search, [ImageMagick](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ImageMagick) claims to be able to resize/crop images, as well as read TIFF. So I would say that it is able to do the job. I know from previous questions that ImageMagick does work with PHP.

Comment: We did end up using ImageMagick, what we discovered was we could convert the Tif to a gif, and it made the gif an animation (basically) so we were able to split that apart.

Comment: That will lose you colour information, though, as GIF has a limited colour range. Pulling single pages out of the TIFF and storing them as single TIFFs or JPGs might work better.